# C++ beginner - simple outputs

Tags: c++

Here I have simple code to serve as a calculator for integers.

```
//Calculator, by Michael Lowry

#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void main ()
{
    int input = 0;
    int input2 = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    int operation = 0;

    cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    cout << "Type 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, or 4 for division" << endl;
    cin >> operation;

    cout << "Enter your second number" << endl;
    cin >> input2;

    if (operation = 1)
    {
        input + input2 == answer;
    }

    if (operation = 2)
    {
        input - input2 == answer;
    }

    if (operation = 3)
    {
        input * input2 == answer;
    }

    if (operation = 4)
    {
        input / input2 == answer;
    }

    cout << "Your answer is " <<
    cout << answer << endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

When I enter "1" for all three inputs, I get the output "Your answer is 6121DBCC0". Why is my answer variable all messed up?

Comment: enable compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your output goes wrong. You should have

```
cout << "Your answer is " << answer << endl;
```

instead of

```
cout << "Your answer is " << 
cout << answer << endl;
```

What happens is that you are writing the outstream object `cout` to output.

Also the comparison operators are wrong, as others have noted. You should have `==` instead of `=` in the `if`-statements and vice versa in the assignment part. Like this:

```
if (operation == 2)
{
    answer = input - input2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors: this is **assigning** a value to the `operation` variable, not comparing it against something:

```
if (operation = 1)
```

it should rather be

```
if(operation == 1)
```

furthermore this doesn't assign the result of `input+input2` to answer but rather makes an unused comparison evaluation

```
input + input2 == answer;
```

and it should rather be

```
answer = input + input2;
```

You should change your code accordingly. Finally this:

```
cout << "Your answer is " << 
cout << answer << endl;
```

is wrong since you're passing the `cout` object along (mind the `operator<<`). That should have been

```
cout << "Your answer is " << answer << endl;
```

Also: `main()` is supposed to return `int`.

Thus your code should have looked like:

```
int main () {
    int input = 0;
    int input2 = 0;
    int answer = 0;
    int operation = 0;

    cout << "Enter your first number" << endl;
    cin >> input; 

    cout << "Type 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication, or 4 for division" << endl;
    cin >> operation;

    cout << "Enter your second number" << endl; 
    cin >> input2;

    if (operation == 1) {
        answer = input + input2;
    }

    if (operation == 2) {
        answer = input - input2;
    }

    if (operation == 3) {
     answer = input * input2;
    }

    if (operation == 4) {
     answer = input / input2;
    }

    cout << "Your answer is " << answer << endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

<kbd>[Try it out](http://ideone.com/GarQce)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First: Use

```
if (operation == 1)
```

instead of

```
if (operation = 1)
```

because `==` is for equality, `=` is for assignment.

Second:

```
answer = input1 + input2;
```

instead of

```
input + input2 == answer;
```

Do this in all `if` statements.

Third: Use

```
cout << "Your answer is "  << answer << endl;
```

to print your answer.

And remember `answer = input / input2` will give you integer division not floating point.

Answer (score 1):

### First mistake

If you want to assign value to variable `answer` you should do:

```
answer = input1 (required operator here) input2;
```

In your code such construction:

```
input - input2 == answer;
```

Is wrong in 2 ways:

1. If you want assign value to answer use assigning`=` not comparing `==` operator.
2. Assigning values goes from right to left, so your desired variable should be on the left side.

### Second Mistake

In line `if (val = yourConstant)` you made very popular mistake - assigning inside if statement. Many languages prohibit such things, because they are hard to detect without debuggining or tests. The code inside if statement will be executed only if `yourConstant` will be more than 0. Instead please use `if (val == yourConstant)` or `if (yourConstant == val)`.

Comment: if the value is a constant, using `if (yourConstant == val)` is recommended as the compiler will help you catch the error easier

Answer (score 0):

So instead of:

```
if (operation = 1)
```

do:

```
if (operation == 1)
```

Also change your output to:
`cout << "Your answer is " << answer << endl;`

Another mistake:

```
input - input2 == answer;
```

This is wrong. You have to make answer equal to `input - input2`. Also there should only be one `=`, because it is not a condition.

So:

```
answer = input - input2;
```

Apply that to all your arithmetic inside the if statements. That should fix it.
But try to not use `system ("PAUSE");` because it has its problems if you transfer your code. Just a suggestion.